# I am trying to execute a sql query using prepared statement but it is returning empty value

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
String sql = "select s_upload_file.NEXTVAL from dual" ;
PreparedStatement ps = con.preparedStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

While execute this I get result set as empty. What is the issue with this..

Comment: what is `s_upload_file.nextvalue` ?

Comment: Upload_file is a table name and it has a sequence number column here I am trying to access it by pseudocolumn .. sorry its Nextval I had edited

Comment: Its running directly... Could you suggest a way to find the next value of the sequence number column in db?

Comment: Did you go through `rs.next()`?

Comment: Thanks hasitha I got the value when iterate through RS.next()..

Comment: @VigneshMurugesan If it helps, So you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try something like this,

```
 String sql = "select s_upload_file.NEXTVAL from dual" ;
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
 ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
 if (rs.next())
 {
   int var2= rs.getInt(1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers already, but I will try to give you a full scope of the answer.

```
public static Connection getConnection_Test() throws Exception{

    try{

        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Database_Name";
        String username = "root";
        String pass = "";
        Class.forName(driver);

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, pass);
        System.out.println("Success!");

        String query = "SELECT S_UPLOAD_FILE.NEXTVAL from dual \n ";

        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            int NEXTVALUE = rs.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(NEXTVALUE);

        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();    

        return conn;
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get values through `rs.next()`,

```
String sql = "select s_upload_file.NEXTVAL from dual";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
synchronized( this ) {
   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
   if(rs.next())
     long nxtVal = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
/* not mandatory but give an alias to your column in select */
if(rs.next()){
   int nextval = rs.getInt(1);
    System.out.println(nextval)
}
```